# Android doesn't allow both contextmenu && optionsmenu?

Tags: android, android-activity, contextmenu, options-menu

i've tried to add an optionsmenu and a contextmenu to one activity, but it doesn't work.

When i create a new XML file in the menu folder, where the XML file for the optionsmenu exists, the whole android app doesn't work, because the R.java file couldn't be created/updated again.

Why this is happening?

Anybody got the same problems?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning after adding your new XML menu?

Comment: Yes, that caused the problem, after i cleaned the project files, this effect occured.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is happening?

Because you have a bug in one of your resource files, or perhaps your manifest, that is preventing `R.java` from being generated. If you are using Eclipse, this error usually appears in the Console tab; if you are building from the command line, you will see a compile error.

Comment: You are right. It is awesome! I forgot in to declare a string for an item. It's very painfull that Eclipse don't show any error.